# подскажите как вывести поля из бд php ajax в html

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

подскажите как вывести поля из бд php ajax. делаю первый раз

html

```
 <div class="reviews">
          <div class="name"></div>
          <div class="message"></div>
    </div>
```

select.js

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'select.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        success: function (data){
            $('.name').text(data.name);
            $('.message').text(data.msg);
        }
        })
```

select.php

```
<?php

require 'connect.php';

$sel = $db->query("SELECT `name`, `msg` FROM reviews")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($sel as $k => $v){
        print_r($v['name']);
        $response = [
            "name" => $v['name'],
            "msg" => $v['msg']
        ];
    }
    json_encode($response);
```

скрин бд - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyikN.png

Comment: print_r() видимо мешает работе, ajax() ожидает json-формат вывода ответа от php-скрипта, закомментируй print_r(), для первого раза неплохо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в части пхп. `$sel` у вас уже готовый массив. не  надо его перебирать и еще что-то с ним делать.

```
$sel = $db->query(...)->fetchAll(...);
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($sel);
exit;
```

html разметка статичная вам тут сильно не поможет. сделайте общий контейнер, куда будете добавлять данные.

```
 <div id="wrapper"></div>
```

отправку аякс запроса проще сделать через `$.get` или `$.getJSON`

```
  $.getJSON("/path/to/select.php", function(data){
      let html = data.map(function(v){
                      // вставить свою разметку 
                      return `<div class="review">${v.name}</div>`;
                   }).join();

      $("#wrapper").html(html);          
  });
```

в целом вы можете сформировать html разметку на сервере, а не передавать данные в json. C технической точки зрения это проще в реализации, и может быть менее эффективно

```
$sel = ....
foreach($sel as $v){
    echo "<div class='review'>{$v['name']}</div>";
}
```

со стороны js

```
$("#wrapper").load("/sel.php");
```

Comment: спасибо только как убрать эти запятые и откуда они взялись https://imgur.com/VgcSifn

Comment: @govnocoder в вашей разметке где то присутствуют, очевидно.

Comment: помогло удаление .join();

Comment: или можно сделать так - .join('')

Comment: а да, действительно.